# Exporting REST Data to CSV in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a python script that uses a function 'get_users' to gather data from a REST API, currently it simply prints to the console. I pulled it from a GitHub repo, I'm trying to modify it to export that data to a csv but have not worked with Python much before. The format of the data in the csv should have the columns: "User, Email, Phone, Push, SMS". Here's the code:

```
import argparse
import sys
def get_users(session):
    sys.stdout.write("Listing All Users' Contact Methods:\n")
    for user in session.iter_all('users'):
        sys.stdout.write("User: ")
        sys.stdout.write(user['name'])
        sys.stdout.write("\n")
        get_contact_methods(user['id'], session)
        sys.stdout.write("-----\n")
get_users(session)
```

I tried using `csv.writer(sys.stdout.write)` at the end of the function but received the TypeError: argument 1 must have a "write" method

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you come from Java and that's why you were trying to print with the console via `sys.stdout.write`. In python you can just use the `print` function to print something to the console and it naturally appends an newline to it. So, it would be something like:

```
def get_users(session):
    print("Listing All Users' Contact Methods:")
    for user in session.iter_all('users'):
        print("User: ")
        print(user['name'])
        print(user['id'], session)
        print("-----")
get_users(session)
```

Now the `sys.stdout.write` is a function that as you've seen prints a string to the stdout. Similiarly `csv.writer` is a function that takes a **file** as an input and not a function.

So your new code will be:

```
#open file
file = open('rest.csv', 'w+', newline='')
#Notice how we pass the file as the argument
writer = csv.writer(file)
for user in session.iter_all('users'):
    #First row which contains the headers
    writer.writerow(["User","Email","Phone","Push","SMS"])
    #Now write all the data
    #I'm assuming the rest api returned a list of dictionary (json objects) in session
    writer.writerow([user['name'],user['email'],user['phone'],user['push'],user['sms'])
file.close()
```

Comment: You are right, I am coming from Java! Thank you for this, the script is up and running and with a bit of tweaking for formatting I should be good to go!